# I'm trying to use a textbox value as a session variable

Tags: php, html, session, textbox

I'm trying to use a textbox value as a session variable when the button is clicked, so far I have it working but it's hardcoded in, how do I get it to use the textbox value instead?

Here's the session code:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['url'] = "url";
?>
```

Here's the textbox:

```
echo "<input type='text' id='starurl' value=''/>";
echo "<br><button onclick='save_a9({$row99['starID']})'>Approve</button><button onclick='save_d9({$row99['starID']})'>Disapprove</button><br>";
```

Here's the save_a9:

```
 function save_a9(id) {
        $.post('response6.php', {starID:id}, 
        function(result) { 
            alert(result); 
            window.location.reload();
    });
}
```

Is this what you mean? the value doesn't need a form, it just needs to go to another page to be used there

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['url']) {
  $_SESSION['url'] = $_GET['url'];
}
?>

echo "<input type='text' id='starurl' value='" . htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['url'])"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are assigning the _SESSION url, you will need to use the posted variable to assign the string.

```
$_SESSION['url'] = $_GET['url'];
```

To do the opposite, and have the textbox show the value of the session, you would:

```
echo "<input type='text' id='starurl' value='" . htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['url']) . "'/>";
```

It is important to note that if you want the text box to actually *do* something, you will need to have the input box wrapped around a form tag.

The `<form>` tag tells the browser where the form starts and ends. You can add all kinds of HTML tags between the `<form>` and `</form>` tags. [(thanks echoecho!)](http://www.echoecho.com/htmlforms03.htm%5C)

If you are working RESTfully, GET should be used for requests where you are only getting data, and POST should be used for requests where you are making something happen.

Some examples:

- GET the page showing a particular SO question
- POST a comment
- Click the "Add to cart" button and send a POST request.

([Thanks Skilldrick!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3477384/2143004))

The form & PHP file would look like this:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['url']) {
  $_SESSION['url'] = $_POST['url'];
}

echo '<form action="POST" method="?">';
echo "<input type='text' id='starurl' value='" . htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['url']) . "'/>";
echo '</form>';
```

You will notice when the form is updated, the session updates too. When you close your browser and open it again, you will see you old contents on the input box. (Press "enter" to save the input box without a submit button).

Comment: it's not a url as such it's a string of characters entered by the user there will also be name

Comment: @babyoth same difference :) I have added some more content to the answer.

Comment: thanks I have added some code to my question to reflect what I think you was saying code wise, let me know if i'm on the right track please

Answer (score 1):

For getting the value from your textbox, first modify your HTML as :

`<input type='text' id='starurl' name='url' value=''/>`

The textbox needs a `name` attribute which is used by the `$_POST`, `$_GET` or `$_REQUEST` superglobals.

Then depending upon your form submission method (GET or POST) :

```
$_SESSION['url'] = $_GET['url']        // Default method for form submission
$_SESSION['url'] = $_POST['url']       // For <form method="post">
$_SESSION['url'] = $_REQUEST['url']    // Works for both
```

**EDIT :**
Since you are using a button onclick event to set the session variable, you can use this (assuming you are using jQuery) :

**Javascript:**

```
$('button').click(function(){
    var url = $('#starurl').val();
    $('#sessionURLDiv').load('save_session_url.php?url='+url);
});
```

**PHP: save_session_url.php :**

```
<?php
session_start();
if ( isset ( $_GET['url'] ) ) {
    $_SESSION['url'] = $_GET['url'];
}
?>
```

**HTML :**
Just add this div anywhere in the page.

```
<div id = "sessionURLDiv"></div>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Can you explain the whole process, what you are trying to achieve?
That might help.

Comment: i'm using a button with an onclick event though. I'm trying to enter a value into a textbox and click the button which added it to the session and is used on another page which update a row in the database, does that help

Comment: What will be showed in this div? <div id = "sessionURLDiv"></div> or will it still blank?

Comment: It will be blank because the PHP is not returning anything.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use this one

//page1.php

```
<form action="page2.php" method="post">

    <input type="text" name="session_value">
    <input type="submit" name="set_session" value="Set Session">

</from>
```

//page2.php

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['set_session'])){
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['url'] = $_POST['session_value'];
    }

?>
```

Comment: i don't want to use a form i want to use a button though