# set php session variable with onblur() to textbox value

Tags: php, session, onblur

Is it actually possible to set a php session variable with onblur() to the value on a textbox.
Research tells me it shouldn't work but:

```
onblur="<?php $_SESSION["limit"] = "3" ?>"
```

appears to. What I want to do is set a session variable so when a link is clicked, the variable takes the value of the textbox.

```
<form method="post" onblur="<?php $_SESSION["limit"] = (this.limitbox.value) ?>">
    <input type="text" name="limitbox" value="0" width="5" style="width:40px;"/ >
    recipients
</form>
```

I understand php is server side but don't know if there is a simple way to do this or to be honest, what way is best. I have checked previous posts but can't find an answer I understand so please don't mark me down if you find one that answers this and you understand it. **This is closest:** [I'm trying to use a textbox value as a session variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18712078/im-trying-to-use-a-textbox-value-as-a-session-variable)

Comment: Not in that way. You have to do a call to a PHP script and set the `$_SESSION` there.

Comment: OK thanks. I won't waste more time on it then.

Answer (score 0):

Using ajax to set session

```html
    // set onblur
    onblur="doAjax(this)"


    // function doAjax to set session
    function doAjax(obj)
    {
      $.ajax({
        url:'file_to_set_session.php',
        dataType:'json',
        method:'get',
        data: {"limit": this.limitbox.value}
        success:function () {
          //do something
        }
      });
    }


    // file_to_set_session.php
    $_SESSION["limit"] = $_GET["limit"];
```